# Background timer task .net Web Api and Xamarin form

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I have been working on a `xamarin` form app. The primary purpose of the app is to let user create a count down timer and if user doesn't stop the timer before it reaches zero then it sends SMS messages to some numbers.

I am using android foreground service to start a timer and display a count down timer. It is working fine, however, this solution is not 100% reliable as SMS will not be sent if for some reason phone is shut down after the timer has stared. Therefore, I would like to move the timer logic to `.Net Web API` (my app is already using `.Net Web API` for other functionality) so that when a user starts the timer, `Web API` on the server tracks the timer for the user who started the timer.

Can someone guide me to implement a reliable solution for web api for above scenario? I have looked at `Hangfire` and other scheduled tasks such as windows service but those seem too complicated for this seemingly easier task. The timer needs to be started and stopped dynamically via `Web API` and if it reaches zero then "SendSMS" method in `Web API` needs to be called.

Comment: You'd be better off using something like an Azure function, or web job that you can actually schedule properly

Comment: @learner, How are you going to send an SMS from Webapi? Do you have a technology already integrated, or are you just going to send something to the phone to have it send an sms?

Comment: also if the timer is less than 90 seconds you can use .Net4.5 backgroundtaskqueue

Answer (score 1):

You can take the advantage from System.Threading.Tasks Assembly.Like this

```
 CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

        private void CancelSendMessageTask()
        {
            tokenSource?.Cancel();
        }

        private void StartTimer()
        {
            int SecondsToWait = 90;
            tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecondsToWait));

            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecondsToWait), tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
                if (t.IsCanceled) return;
                SendSMS();
            });
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [this example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7346/Sending-SMS-using-NET-through-a-Web-service) or other similar to send sms and implement the countdown timer on the web service side.

then you use `HTTPClient` class on `Xamarin` to inform the web service that the timer needs to be started or stoped.

Let me know if you need a code example.